# Counting an item and stuffing the results

Tags: sql, sql-server

is this possible, i have results like below and want to stuff or combine each id

```
Num    id   RMA
item1   1   0
item1   1   0
item1   1   0
item1   8   1
item1   8   1
item1   8   1
item1   1   0
item1   1   0
item1   1   0
item2   8   1
item2   8   1
item2   8   1
item2   8   1
item2   8   1
item2   8   1
item2   8   1
item2   1   0
```

i would like to get the results like below

```
item1   id1=3,id8=3,id1=3
item2   id8=7,id1=1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  "to stuff" is not a verb normally associated with query processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not difficult, however, you will need to create some additional steps, see the code bellow:

```
DECLARE @items TABLE (Num varchar(10) , id INT, RMA int , _group int default(0) )
declare @gIndcator int = 0 , @old_id int = 0 

insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item1' ,    1 , 0
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item1' ,    1 , 0
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item1' ,    1 , 0
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item1' ,    8 , 1
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item1' ,    8 , 1
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item1' ,    8 , 1
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item1' ,    1 , 0
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item1' ,    1 , 0
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item1' ,    1 , 0
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item2' ,    8 , 1
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item2' ,    8 , 1
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item2' ,    8 , 1
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item2' ,    8 , 1
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item2' ,    8 , 1
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item2' ,    8 , 1
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item2' ,    8 , 1
insert @items (num,id,rma) select 'item2' ,    1 , 0


UPDATE @items
SET @gIndcator = _group = case when @old_id <> id then @gIndcator +  1 else @gIndcator end 
    , @old_id = id 


select * from @items

select distinct
    num
  , ids = stuff((
      select ',id'+convert(varchar(12),b.id) + '=' +convert(varchar(12),b._count)
      from (
SELECT num, id , _group, COUNT(1) _count
FROM  @items c
where a.Num = c.Num
group by Num, id,_group)  b
      where a.Num = b.Num
      order by b.Num,_group
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
      ,1,1,'')
from @items a
```

item1   id1=3,id8=3,id1=3

item2   id8=7,id1=1

Comment: thank you very much.. exactly what i wanted, now i have some research to do

Comment: You're welcome. Please vote on the answer as "accepted" so she will appear right after the question

Answer (score 1):

If it's SQL server:

You can use a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT    Num
          ,id
          ,COUNT(RMA) AS Count_RMA
FROM      Table
GROUP BY  Num
          ,id
```

It will output a table that counts each `RMA` for each unique `Num` and `id` combinaison.

Like this:

```
Num    id   Count_RMA
item1   1   6
item1   8   3
item2   8   7
item2   1   1
```

Comment: that does not give me what i am looking for as you have item1 resulting in id1=6,id8=3 when i need id1=3,id8=3,id1=3.. but if i add the date column i should get my answer.. thanks.

Comment: My pleasure ! Yes, you can then ``GROUP BY`` the date and add it to your ``SELECT`` and you'll get what you are looking for !

Answer (score 0):

It looks something like this:

```
select t.*,
       stuff( (select ',' + cast(id as varchar(max)) + '=' + cast(cnt as varchar(max))
               from t tt
               where t.num = tt.num
               group by id
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
             ) as 
from (select num from t) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE(Num , id, RMA)
AS
(
SELECT 'item1',   1 ,  0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'item1',   1 ,  0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'item1',   1 ,  0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'item1',   8 ,  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'item1',   8 ,  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'item1',   8 ,  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'item1',   1 ,  0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'item1',   1 ,  0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'item1',   1 ,  0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2',   8 ,  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2',   8 , 1  UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2',   8 ,  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2',   8 ,  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2',   8 ,  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2',   8 ,  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2',   8 ,  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2',   1 ,  0
)
,Final
AS
(
SELECT Num,idval,cnt AS COUNT_RMA From
(
SELECT NUM,'    id'+CASt(id AS Varchar(2))AS idval,cnt, ROW_NUMBER()OVEr(Partition by NUm,Cnt order by Num)AS Seq
From
(
SELECT NUm,id,COUNT(Id)Over(Partition by Num ,id order by Num)Cnt from CTE
)Dt
)Fnl
where Fnl.Seq=1
)
SELECT DISTINCT num, STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+CAST(''+CAST(idval AS VARCHAR)+'='+CAST(COUNT_RMA AS VARCHAR) AS VARCHAR(100))
From Final I WHERE O.Num=I.Num foR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') As Requiredvalue
from Final O
```